# yii2 return ActiveRecord attribute as JSON with other name

Tags: php, json, api, activerecord, yii2

When I select ActiveRecord

```
$models = Model::find()
        ->select(['someothername' => 'name'])->all();
```

and add this 'someothername' as public property to the model, I can then access it

```
$model->someothername
```

But now I need to return this field in JSON

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
return $models;
```

How can I do it? Should I add 'someothername' to attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Try to override `fields()` method in your active record.

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    $fields['someothername'] = $this->someothername;

    return $fields;
}
```

[Docs about fields method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#data-exporting)

Answer (score 1):

Just [try](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-json.html) Class yii\helpers\Json;

```
$data = Youremodel::model()->find();
JSON::encode($data);
```